# Case Statement Not Working - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, case-statement

In my project I have a list of clients that have unique commission calculations (ex. Client_1 has a 0.1% commission rate, whereas Client_2 has a 0.25% commission rate).

In my VBA code I made special cases, that vary by the client_id. The problem I'm getting with this code is that even though I put in a special ID, it jumps over the case (ex. if klienta_nr = 100, it skips over the Case klienta_nr = 100 and returns the Case Else). How can I fix this issue?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim klienta_nr As Long
Dim ISIN As String
Dim Cena As Double
Dim Skaits As Double
Dim Komisija As Double
Dim vk As String

Set kSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("komisijas")


klienta_nr = Range("B2").Value
ISIN = Range("E2").Value
Cena = Range("H2").Value
Skaits = Range("I2").Value
vk = Range("B2").Value

Select Case klienta_nr

Case klienta_nr = 100

            If klienta_nr = 100 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE") Then
                Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.01
                Range("K2").Value = Komisija
                End If
            If klienta_nr = 100 And Komisija <= 30 Then
                Range("K2").Value = 30
                End If

            'Case where klient is special, but ISIN doesn't apply
            If klienta_nr = 100 And (Left(ISIN, 2) <> "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IE") Then
                Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.003
                If Komisija >= 40 Then
                    Range("K2").Value = 40
                    End If
            End If


 Case klienta_nr = 105

            If klienta_nr = 105 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE") Then
                Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.01
                Range("K2").Value = Komisija
                End If
            'Set 30 EUR Min
            If klienta_nr = 105 And Komisija <= 30 Then
                Range("K2").Value = 30
                End If

    'End If


 Case klienta_nr = 110

            If klienta_nr = 110 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "NO" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "SE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "DK" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FI" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IS" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "LT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "EE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "AT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "BE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "ES" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "PT") Then
                Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.002
                Range("K2").Value = Komisija
                End If

            If klienta_nr = 110 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "US") Then
                Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.002
                End If

            If klienta_nr = 110 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "UK") Then
                Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.002
                Range("K2").Value = Komisija
                End If

            If klienta_nr = 110 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "CH") Then
                Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.002
                Range("K2").Value = Komisija
                End If
            'Set 20 [valūte] MIN
            If klienta_nr = 110 And Komisija <= 20 Then
                Range("K2").Value = 20
                End If


Case klienta_nr = 115

            If klienta_nr = 115 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "NO" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "SE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "DK" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FI" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IS" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "LT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "EE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "AT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "BE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "ES" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "PT") Then
                Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.002
                Range("K2").Value = Komisija
                End If

            If klienta_nr = 115 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "US") Then
                Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.002
                End If

            If klienta_nr = 115 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "UK") Then
                Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.002
                Range("K2").Value = Komisija
                End If

            If klienta_nr = 115 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "CH") Then
                Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.002
                Range("K2").Value = Komisija
                End If
            'Set 20 [valūte] MIN
            If klienta_nr = 115 And Komisija <= 20 Then
                Range("K2").Value = 20
                End If


 Case klienta_nr = 120

            If klienta_nr = 120 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "US") Then
                Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.0027
                Range("K2").Value = Komisija
                End If
            'Set 40 USD MIN
            If klienta_nr = 120 And Komisija <= 40 Then
                Range("K2").Value = 40
                End If



'Non-special klient cases
Case Else
    If Not Application.Match(klienta_nr, kSheet.Range("A2:A100")) Then

         If Right(vk, 1) = 1 Or Right(vk, 1) = 8 Then
            Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.003
            Range("K2").Value = Komisija
            End If

        If Right(vk, 1) = 7 Then
            Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.01
            Range("K2").Value = Komisija
            End If
        'Komisija MAX is 40, so anything >=40 equals 40
        If Komisija >= 40 Then
            Range("K2").Value = 40
            End If
    End If
   End Select               
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Select Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) only needs criteria in

```
Select Case klienta_nr
```

And not in the Case part as below:

Change

```
Case klienta_nr = 105
```

to

```
Case 105
```

Comment: Simple fix, but didn't know this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your `Select Case klienta_nr` , and then the first case is `Case 100`, you don't repeat underneath `If klienta_nr = 100` , since you already checked that in your `Case`.

Change your `Select Case` structure to:

```
Select Case klienta_nr

Case 100

    If (Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE") Then
        Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.01
        Range("K2").Value = Komisija
    End If
    If Komisija <= 30 Then
        Range("K2").Value = 30
    End If

    'Case where klient is special, but ISIN doesn't apply
    If (Left(ISIN, 2) <> "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IE") Then
        Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.003
        If Komisija >= 40 Then
            Range("K2").Value = 40
        End If
    End If

Case 105

    If (Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE") Then
        Komisija = (Cena * Skaits) * 0.01
        Range("K2").Value = Komisija
    End If
    'Set 30 EUR Min
    If Komisija <= 30 Then
        Range("K2").Value = 30
    End If

' add here your other cases...


End Select
```